# Why pass jQuery as an argument to (function($){..})(jQuery) closure wrapper, instead of local var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The closure wrapper `(function($){..})(jQuery);` is a great way to have local variables instead of global ones. Both `$` and any variable and local function defined within the wrapper is visible only within the wrapper, not outside. This is great, and I use it all the time.

```
(function($){
  [..]
})(jQuery);
```

However, I have been wondering why we pass `jQuery` (and possibly other stuff) as an argument, instead of using a local variable declaration.

```
(function(){
  var $ = jQuery;
  [..]
})();
```

Wouldn't this work just as fine, and be more transparent?

Comment: Because you can pass something else that's not jQuery but implements a similar interface, such as Zepto. Then the only change to your code is at the closure invoking line -> `(function($) {})(Zepto)`. Same goes with other popular libraries - lodash instead of underscore etc. You also don't pollute global name space.

Comment: So it is mostly just a matter of taste, and popularity?

Comment: @Mjh - I don't think that makes a compelling argument, since the same kind of change could be wrought with the direct assignment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - you're missing the bigger picture here. Module loaders operate this way. It's an elegant way of passing dependencies without relying on global state. A module such as jQuery doesn't have to be globally defined or available with an identifier. We can remove jQuery out of the picture and use some other popular library so it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Mjh - I can see that, sure, that was my initial thought when I saw the question. However, the way your initial comment reads isn't as compelling as the second argument's more specific use-case. `;)`

Comment: One advantage to putting the variable assignment at the top is that you don't have to go to the end of the IIFE to find out which object has been assigned to *$*.

Comment: @Mjh—in the OP, jQuery **must** be defined as a global in both cases, there is no lack of "pollution" here. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - then judging by your comment no one is allowed to present a general valid use case, because it happens that OP used jQuery in his example?

Comment: @mjh—my comment was regarding "*You also don't pollute global name space*". All of the variables passed to the functions must be in the global space already (whether it's jQuery or something else).

Comment: @RobG - really, all the variables passed to the functions must be in **global** space? I'll assume that was lapsus calami.

Comment: @Mjh—in the context of the OP, yes. How else would you pass a reference to, say, a library base object (e.g. jQuery), to the function?

Comment: @RobG - but pay close attention to what you wrote - which is why I said it's probably lapsus calami. I can think of a few ways how to have jQuery defined non-globally, require.js pops to mind. But since when are we scoping our answers to an exception, such as this one? There are thousands of libraries and someone reading what you wrote here will falsely conclude that all variables passed to functions must be in global space. Now, I am 100% sure you know that's not true but thinking about future visitors and young developers - it's *quite* misleading and teaches people wrong.

Comment: @Mjh The OP (=me) is asking about a very common pattern, and I have only ever seen global variables being passed in to these functions. And what else would you have, if this is the top-level closure of a script file? "will falsely conclude that all variables passed to functions must be in global space" I doubt it. I am curious about your non-global solution, but I suspect it will look quite different to this typical pattern and risk to be off-topic within this thread.

Comment: @Mjh—I wrote "*In the OP…*", "*…to the functions…*" and "*…in the context of the OP…*", so I'm referring to the OP. Of course all values passed to functions don't need to be global, but using the pattern in the OP (which is global code) they do. The question isn't about require.js or module loaders.

Comment: @donquixote my "solution" isn't anything different, it consists of passing a variable to a closure. The only thing I tend to avoid is having libraries exposed globally and reason is that you can overwrite them anywhere and then good luck finding the culprit. I also shared my *opinion* on why you would explicitly pass `jQuery` to the closure as argument. From what I can tell, we're all on the same side in this matter and if my comments brought the confusion -  I do apologize.

Comment: "avoid is having libraries exposed globally" so how does this look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see one reason when former way is better:

`(function(){
  var $ = jQuery;
  [..]
  var jQuery = foo;
})();`

In this example variable "$" will be undefined because of hoisting.

Comment: Nice one. Usually this will not happen, but by putting it in the parameters, you don't even need to review your code for stuff like this.

Comment: That, in my opinion, is the smallest of the small edge case.

Comment: I always prefer the impossible over the unlikely, especially when choosing a pattern that I am going to use in every piece of code I write.

Comment: I think I'm just going to go back to bed.

Comment: If you're going to those lengths, then: `var jQuery = foo; (function($){...}(jQuery))` is going to fail miserably too.

Comment: @RobG But your example is failing in both scenarios, so it does not make either of them preferable.

Comment: @donquixote—that's the point, there is no foolproof solution.

Comment: @RobG Well, it's a popular pattern to solve a specific problem. The scenario you describe could be, for instance, if you want to operate with different versions of jQuery simultaneously. In this case you might want something like this `(function($){..})(jQversion('1.11'))`. Or maybe you know a trick to totally avoid global symbols. Sounds like a new and different topic :)

Comment: "I always prefer the impossible over the unlikely" - I should add: especially for code I read from other people who I don't trust (which is everyone, including my past self).

Answer (score 2):

There's an advantage in terms of code length. It saves a few characters (bytes...). It's not much, but if you have to choose between the 2, the first example is shorter.

In the sake of minification, it's also possible (and to some degree common) to use an "unset" variable to serve as an undefined match like this:

```
(function(r,u){if(r.missingProp===u)alert('undefined!')})({realProp:1})
```

Since `u` isn't passed a value during the call, it will equal `undefined`

Comment: Is this a trick to be done automatically by the minifier, or sth you want to do manually? In the former case I don't really care, in the latter case I strongly object to it :)

Comment: And yes it is shorter, but it seems to be feel mysterious to a lot of people, judging by the many questions on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @donquixote - I didn't try to convince you to do anything :-). I'm just stating why sometimes usage of input parameters can reduce code size. BTW, you could also do that instead of "real variables", to spare the `var x,y,z;` as long as these variables don't need immediate initialization. Again, I'm not saying it's a super-strong don't-even-argue type of reason, but if you have to choose between the 2, I see an advantage here

Comment: It's a tradeoff, clarity vs brevity. In this case I would opt for clarity, with respect to other people and my future self. The `(function($){})(jQuery)` pattern is a bit different, because it is so wide-spread and familiar. And because of @Rafał's point above.